# Enumerate rows with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using python 3.7.1 with openpyxl to gather information from an API. The issue is that I am having is that the last result is getting written to a row instead of all the results going down to the next available. Here is my script. I have tried with and without the row+=1 and still keep getting the same results. I should also mention that each process should have multiple netconn's so column c is where I am having the issue. So the spreadsheet should show a process name then all the netconn's that process has made.

```
ws1 = wb.create_sheet("Sheet_A")
ws1.title = "Computer Name"
ws1['A1'] = "Computer Name"
ws1['B1'] = "Process"
ws1['C1'] = "Remote Port"
ws1['D1'] = "Local Port"
ws1['E1'] = "Netconn Time"
ws1['F1'] = "Netconn Time"
c = CbResponseAPI()
            
# rows = 1

base_query = c.select(Process).where('(ipaddr:152.32.109.50 OR ipaddr:112.206.173.123 OR ipaddr:203.88.149.10 OR ipaddr:203.88.149.10 OR ipaddr:152.32.109.50 OR ipaddr:110.54.237.110 OR ipaddr:110.54.237.110 OR ipaddr:49.144.97.212 OR ipaddr:49.144.97.212 OR ipaddr:152.32.109.50 OR ipaddr:152.32.109.50 OR ipaddr:130.105.243.51 OR ipaddr:152.32.108.202 OR ipaddr:152.32.108.202 OR ipaddr:152.32.108.202 OR ipaddr:110.54.157.221 OR ipaddr:130.105.243.51 OR ipaddr:122.53.99.235 OR ipaddr:122.53.99.235 OR ipaddr:152.32.109.50 OR ipaddr:152.32.109.50 OR ipaddr:152.32.109.50 OR ipaddr:152.32.109.50)')

for i, proc in enumerate (base_query):
        # print (proc)
        ws1[f'A{i+2}'] = proc.hostname
        ws1[f'B{i+2}'] = proc.process_name
        # rows+=1
        for netconn in proc.netconns:
        # print (netconn)
                ws1[f'c{i+2}'] = netconn.remote_ip
                ws1[f'd{i+2}'] = netconn.remote_port
                ws1[f'e{i+2}'] = netconn.local_port
                ws1[f'f{i+2}'] = netconn.timestamp
```

Comment: Please don't use `ws['A1']` for this kind of thing, use `ws.cell(row=1, col=1)` or `ws.iter_rows()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using simplified data (as I don't have Carbon Black api):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from collections import namedtuple

# create workbook and sheet, fields
work_book = Workbook()
work_book.create_sheet("Sheet_A")

work_sheet = work_book.active
work_sheet.title = "Test"
work_sheet['A1'] = "Characters"
work_sheet['B1'] = "Numbers"

# generating test data
data = namedtuple('data', 'character number')
some_data = [data(character=c, number=n) for c, n in zip('abcde', (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))]

# inserting data to sheet
for index, data in enumerate(some_data):
    work_sheet.cell(index + 2, 1).value = data.character
    work_sheet.cell(index + 2, 2).value = data.number

# printing data
print(f'Sheet: {work_sheet.title}')
for row in work_sheet:
    a, b = row
    print(str(a.value).ljust(12), str(b.value).ljust(22))
```

Result:

```
Sheet: Test  
Characters   Numbers    
a            1         
b            2         
c            3         
d            4        
e            5
```